# Nginx proxy automatic subfolder

Tags: drupal, nginx, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I am new to Nginx.I am trying to setup VPS (Nginx port 80 and apache port 8080) has ability :
- Using Nginx as webserver directly.
- Using Nginx as proxy in front of Apache backend.
Follow :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-14-04-droplet

As knowledge with apache,when I add domain abc.com,and add 3 subfolder(contain may be add more in future),each of them is Drupal project.I could access abc.com/a ,abc.com/b ,abc.com/c without any problem with .htaccess .But with both using Nginx directly or use it as proxy,does it have a way to apply nginx conf for all subfolder?

Eg: Here is my demo site http://gravitydemo.com/cerelac
cerelac is my project.When access it,I just access index.php.All other url with rewrite mod is gone.

So my question is : How to config rewrite rule for all subfolder? And when I add new project as subfolder (name D),how to it automatically apply this rules to run as Apache?

Comment: Why are you putting Nginx in front of Apache? Just pick one or the other. They're both very capable web servers, and there's no need to run both.

Comment: I heard about Nginx is good for serve static content and consume less Ram than Apache.So I just left php request to Apache and leave the rest for Nginx